# Limit show action with condition to 404 when not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want to limit the *show* action on my `PostsController` to only allow *published* posts.

This is what I have:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by slug: params[:slug], published: true
end
```

I would expect this to throw a `404`. It does if I attempt to access a non-existing slug. But if I attempt to access a slug that does exist, but is unpublished, it returns a *200* and an *empty* view.

I realize I could resolve this with a simple `if`. However, I'm wondering if there is a *Rails-way* to:

- find or fail
- limit the route *pre-check* to only published posts

Answer (score 4):

use `#find_by!` instead of `#find_by` to throw an exception when no record is found

Comment: it raises an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by! . i'd expect it to raise a 404 . but if its the status code youre interested in, you can use `#find_by` and manually set the response code when it doesnt find one

Answer (score 2):

```
@post = Post.where(slug: params[:slug], published: true).first!
```

`first!` raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if no record is found.

Comment: Doh. I suppose that's rather obvious.

Comment: Does `RecordNotFound` result in a 404?

Comment: Fair. Although my rspecs expect a 404. Must I change those to check for this error.

Comment: use `expect(...).to raise_error(RecordNotFound)` in specs

Comment: Seems to not be so straightforward for a *feature* test. Hence why I was checking for a 404.